# How to set constraints on weights based on other weights in the same layer [Pytorch]

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

As a simple example, take a neural network with 4 input nodes and 1 output node. I would like to take the 4 corresponding weights and set the constraint W1 < W2 < W3 < W4. Is this possible in Pytorch?